# Как передать в скрипт значения $_SESSION[id]?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, mysql

**Вопрос решен на 50%.**
**С передачей $_SESSION[id] разобрались, помогите перенести данные пользователя `$myrow[id];` в обработчик (PS: данные извлекаются при входе на страницу для каждого пользователя в отдельности!!)**

Вот сам скрипт. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы ему передавались значения `$_SESSION[id]`?!

```
<form id="tweetForm" action="submit.php" method="post">

    <textarea name="inputField" id="inputField" tabindex="1" rows="2" cols="40" ></textarea>
    <input class="submitButton inact" style="margin-right:20px;" name="submit" type="submit" value="update" disabled="disabled" />
    </form>

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: submitData,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('ul.statuses li:first-child').before(msg);
            $("ul.statuses:empty").append(msg);

            $('#lastTweet').html($('#inputField').val());

            $('#inputField').val('');
            recount();
        }
    }

});
```

И вот сам файл `submit`:

```
require "db.php";
if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
$_POST['inputField']=stripslashes($_POST['inputField']);
if(mb_strlen($_POST['inputField']) < 1 || mb_strlen($_POST['inputField'])>91140)
die("0");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO demo SET tw='".$_POST['inputField']."',dt=NOW(),sender='".$_SESSION['id']."',wallid='".$myrow['id']."'");

echo formatTw($_POST['inputField'],time());
```

Подскажите, почему данные сессии и данные страницы не заносятся в mysql? Что нужно исправить, чтобы код стал работать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: session_start(); первой строкой

Comment: а как передать значение myrow[id] оно было на странице с которой отправляли ?

Comment: Если я правильно понял. Если нет — объясняйте понятней.

    $_SESSION['id'] = $myrow['id'];

Comment: Когда мы переходим на страницу пользователя то у нас извлекаются данные пользователя в переменную $myrow,по этой переменной мы узнаем какой id стены на странице пользователя,и извлекаем данные или заносим,первое то что мы передаем обработчику это session[id] а потом мы должны передать id пользователя чья эта страница,а эти данные извлекаются на страницу с которой отправляется сообщение обработчику,Подскажите как теперь можно передать myrow[id] обработчику ?

Comment: @OverLoader, снова вы.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите, почему данные сессии и
> данные страницы не заносятся в mysql?

Если вы вот так записываете в БД

```
INSERT INTO demo SET...
```

то данные туда никогда не попадут!

Нужно

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(...)
```

Comment: Хорошо!А как можно обработчику передать значение myrow[id] со страницы с которой шло отправление ?

Comment: внимательно перечитать все комментарии и сделать все правильно!

Answer (score 0):

Ваш запрос подвержен SQL инъекции. Используйте функцию mysql_escape_string()
Синтаксис SQL команды INSERT не верный, вот пример

```
INSERT INTO `user21649_video`.`articles` (`ID`, `Title`, `Description`, `Dates`, `ID_cata`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '2012-08-15', '1')
```